# Can you switch html pages inside others using js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_image
this is about changing html content with js, but it is about images. is it possible to do something like this too, so the same but doing it with a new html file so that you can switch pages inside a page?
So the plan is to replace the html underneath (with id="id") by another html file using js.

```js
document.getElementById("id").src = "otherfile.html";
```

```html
<html>
<body>
hey guys! here is my html page. If you click underneath, content will be changed.
<html id="id">
<body>
here is the text that will change if id="id" will be changed by a different html file
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, I know that this won't work.
But is there a way to archieve this?

Thank you if you are reading and trynna answer my post, I understand if it's a messy and shitty question so shoutout to you.

Comment: avoid using w3schools, use mdn - w3schools is full of bad practice and incorrect code

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I don't use w3schools myself, but I recall reading they've improved a lot during the past few years?

Comment: @Stijn they have considerably since back in the day (so to speak) but it's still got enough bad practices to avoid

Comment: @Stijn, going from "awful" to "bad" is an improvement, but it doesn't make w3schools _good_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the contents of a `div` instead the whole `HTML`? Via jQuery.

```
<div id="dynamic-html">
    here is the text that will change if id="id" will be changed by a different html file
</div>

$( "#btnChangeHTML" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dynamic-html" ).html("<div  class='myclass'>This is the custom HTML</div>");
});
```

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/u8xsker2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Read about iframe. Perhaps it is what you want.